# Evaluating requirements in python using string.isalpha, return always True

Tags: python, string, boolean, evaluation, requirements

I'm trying to define a function in Python3 that evaluates if the input meets the given requirements; which are: must be between 3 to 20 caracters long (inclusive), must be only letters and apostrophe and "-" and space.

```
def validateFirstname(firstname):
    #Local Variable
    hasFirstname = False
    Caracterslist = "/'/-"

    if (len(firstname) >= 3 and len(firstname) <= 20 and
        firstname.isalpha(), firstname.isspace(), (firstname in Caracterslist)):
        hasFirstname = True
    return hasFirstname

firstname = str(input("Enter your first name: "))
if (validateFirstname(firstname)):
    print("Your first name is: ", firstname)
else:
    print("The first name you entered ", firstname, "is not valid!")
```

Actually, it return True even if the first name is longer than 20 caracters and even if it contains numbers…

I cannot understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the check into a sub-function to clean the code:

```
def validateFirstname(firstname):
    def validchar(c):
        return c.isalpha() or c.isspace() or (c in "'-")
    total = sum(1 for c in firstname if validchar(c))
    return 3 <= total <= 20 and total == len(firstname)
```

Comment: It almost works! The thing is if  use any of the ' or -, it always return false….

Answer (score 3):

In your expression:

```
if (len(firstname) >= 3 and len(firstname) <= 20 and
        firstname.isalpha(), firstname.isspace(), (firstname in Caracterslist)):
```

This following part is being evaluated as a tuple (*note the commas*):

```
(len(firstname) >= 3 and len(firstname) <= 20 and
        firstname.isalpha(), firstname.isspace(), (firstname in Caracterslist))
```

This is essentially of the form:

```
(a and b and c, f, g, h)
```

And hence is evaluated as a tuple.

This tuple, regardless of its contents will evaluate to `True`, e.g:

```
>>> if (False,False,False):
    print "Was True"

Was True
```

This happens because the *tuple* itself is considered in a `True`/`False` sense.

In Python the following values are considered false [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> 1. None
> 2. False
> 3. zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
> 4. any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> 5. any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> 6. instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a
>    **nonzero**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False. [1](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

As the tuple is **not** empty `(,)` it will be considered `True`, hence the expression evaluates to `True`. You need to replace the `,`'s with an appropriate Boolean operator. This will stop the expression being treated as a tuple becase it will be of the form `(a)`

---

There are logical problems in your expression, you'll need to work out the correct chain of conditions for your logic. However you must fix the tuple creation problem (above) as well. Appropriate logic may be:

```
#if fistname is not all spaces, and is of correct length, and (is either all alphabetical or contains a character in characterlist)
if not firstname.isspace() and 3 <= len(firstname) <= 20 and (firstname.isalpha() or any(c in firstname for c in Caracterslist)):
    return firstname
```

Comment: @user2357112 is he removes the comma he will be left with `if(a and b and c and d ...):` which won't be treated as a tuple.

Comment: @HennyH: The thing is, the logical conjunction of those tests does not form a correct implementation of what the OP actually wants.

Comment: @user2357112 I see, there are two issues. firstly the tuple problem and then the incorrect logic

Comment: (firstname in Caracterslist) is to evaluate if there is an hyphen or an apostrophe in the string… @HennyH

Comment: I tried! It almost worked… you forgot the `code`firstname.isspace`code` 
Also, when I tried Bob 99, it returned True… But when I tried Marie-Philippe, it returned True also!

Comment: @djwelcome I get `False` for Bob 99 and `True` for Marie-Philippe

Comment: @HennyH yes it works for me too! I guess I made a mistake earlier… Thanks btw!

Answer (score 1):

```
firstname.isalpha(), firstname.isspace(), (firstname in Caracterslist))
```

This part is the problem. What you want to do is test whether each character in `firstname` is a letter, space, apostrophe, or hyphen. This doesn't do that. Unless you were actually expecting this code to do that, it's not particularly relevant what it actually does; it suffices to say that it does something completely unlike what you wanted.

Here's a code snippet that actually does check each letter against the constraints. It loops over each character, checking whether it's a letter or one of the few allowed non-letter characters:

```
for letter in firstname:
    if not (firstname.isalpha() or firstname in " '-"):
        return False
```

You could also use set operations to check whether the set of allowed characters is a superset of the set of input characters:

```
import string

#string.letters is a string containing all ASCII letters
if not set(string.letters + " '-").issuperset(firstname):
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import ascii_letters

if ((len(firstname) in range(3, 20)) and all(c in ascii_letters+" '-" for c in firstname):
    #do things
```